# Media Queries dont work in JSX files (React)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So im trying to make the react app responsive without bootstrap but everytime  I add a media query in a react component's(jsx file)CSS **(src/App.css)**,it just doesnt work.
I tried doing the same in the **public/index.html** and its **styles.css** and it works there.
eg I have a component called NavBar.jsx  **src/Components/NavBar.jsx** that im calling it in my **src/App.js** and i styled using **src/App.css** and everything works fine except the media queries

**Heres the NavBar component**

```html
import React from "react";
function NavBar(){
  return <div class = "NavBar">
    <div class = "background-foundation">
      <div class = "list" >
      <div><li class = "items"><a href="#">Home </a></li></div>
      <div><li class = "items"><a href="#">About</a></li></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
export default NavBar;
```

**Heres its CSS**

```css
.background-foundation{
  background-color:#035aa6; 
  padding : 20px 0px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .background-foundation{
    width :90%;
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `class`, try `className`

```
import React from "react";
function NavBar(){
  return <div className = "NavBar">
    <div className = "background-foundation">
      <div className = "list" >
      <div><li className = "items"><a href="#">Home </a></li></div>
      <div><li className = "items"><a href="#">About</a></li></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
export default NavBar;
```